# How to create an IBAction for a button programmatically-created based on user input

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating a small project involving the creation of a UIButton based user input.

I know how to programmatically add the button but I am not sure how I can make the button perform actions I want it to perform. I know for a UIButton created directly on the storyboard, an IBAction can be linked into the file to do so. Can anyone show me how this can be done with a programmatically created button?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use addTarget to bind an action to a method

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){
    print("button Clicked")
}
```

then add target to button

```
var button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIControl` function `addTarget(_:action:for:)`. You specify a target, an action (using the swift `#selector(actionName(_:)` syntax), and the event(s) for which you want the button to trigger the action.

When you're looking in the docs on an object like UIButton, remember to check it's ancestor classes as well. The `addTarget(_:action:for:)` function is defined in UIControl.