# How to add an action to a UIBarButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I've been creating a small iOS app using Swift just for fun, and I have already decided that I want a notification box (a bell-shaped button you can click on to check if there's any notification), and I also wanted to add the bell-shaped button to every screen.
So, I decided to make a base view controller and have other view controllers inherit it. However, that's when my problem arose; I have no idea how to add an action func for that button. Since I create the bell-shaped button programmatically, I cannot just `^ drag` and create a new IBaction.

I found this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049212/how-to-create-an-ibaction-for-a-button-programmatically-created-based-on-user-in), but this is for a UIButton, not for a UIBarButton, and it didn't work for me.

Sorry for this long question. Below is a simple, one-sentenced question:
**MY PROBLEM**
How can I add an action to a UIBarButton programmatically?

**UPDATE**
Here's my base view controller:

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add a notification button
        let notificationButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "bell.fill"))
        notificationButton.tintColor = .black
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = notificationButton
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**UPDATE2**

Here's my new code:

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add a notification button
        let notificationButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(systemName: "bell.fill"),
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(notificationButtonPressed)
        )
        
        notificationButton.tintColor = .black
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = notificationButton
    }
    
    @objc func notificationButtonPressed() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are creating your `UIBarButtonItem` right now?

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: I'm surprised that that actually compiles! I can see where your confusion came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a target-action pair to the initialiser of `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(systemName: "bell.fill"), 
    style: .plain, 
    target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped)
)

// somewhere in your view controller:

@objc func buttonTapped() {
    // do something when the bar button is tapped
}
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init).

This is similar to `UIButton`'s [`addTarget(_:action:for:_)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) method, if you are familiar with that.

Comment: My code does not work. Please see my code and tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @asnerdyasSteveWozniak What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: the `print` does not show up.

Comment: @asnerdyasSteveWozniak I cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The base view controller is complete; I just copied the entire code and pasted it there in the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It actually works well.